# Html file in subfolder can't find css in another subfolder

Tags: html, css, path, subdirectory

I usually read a lot and find solutions in here, but this time it seems I can't get this to work.
I have basic knowledge of html/css/js so this problem might have a banal solution which I can't see.

My website has roughly this structure at its root:

```
index.html

/css/style.css

/js/jquery.min.js

/folder/page.html
```

In my page.html head I have:

```
<script src="/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<noscript>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style.css" type="text/css" />
</noscript>
```

(This is a simplified version, I have other css and js files)
The problem is that this way of pointing to a folder works with js but doesn't with css. If I take a look to the console errors, I see that the css file was mistakenly believed to be in /folder/css/style.css

I also tried using "../" and the same thing happens: works with the js but not with the css folder.

Is the `<noscript>` tag interfering somehow?

Thanks for your help!

---

Edit:
I SOLVED IT! There was a js overriding it all, telling which css to load according to the window size, so I corrected the paths in the js with "../" and now they all point to the root folder correctly! Thanks for somehow putting me on the right track! ;)

Comment: and does it work when you remove the `<noscript>` tag

Comment: try this `../css/style.css`.

Comment: Yes @wouter140 it does, and I knew it, but still... the same head in index.html DOES display css correctly. My pages are based on a template and I have no precise explanation about why the <noscript> tag is needed. My guess is that there's some js happening before loading the css?

Comment: @wouter140 I SOLVED IT! There was a js overriding it all, telling which css to load according to the window size, so I corrected the paths in the js with "../" and now they all point to the root folder correctly! Thanks for somehow putting me on the right track! ;)

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
<noscript>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/style.css" type="text/css" />
</noscript>
```

Keep in mind that it will work only when you have javascript disabled. More info about noscript tag here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/noscript